# Save opencv FlannBasedMatcher from python

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.7, flann

I am trying to save a FlannBasedMatcher created and train with opencv-python 4.5.5.62.

The save function of the class only save the parameters. I can also access to the trainDescriptors, but what I would like is to save the flann once trained. Be able to reload it from another python script.

Does anybody have any clue on it ?

Code example would be something like (I know the code is useless and ugly but an example can sometimes help to understand the problem) :

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Creating random data
datas = np.random.rand(50000, 512)
datas = np.float32(datas)

# Creating the FlannBasedMatcher and train it
flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
flann.add([datas])
flann.train()

# Here I am able to do knnMatch search in 'flann'

# Not existing function that I am looking for
flann.saveTrainedModel("my_file_path")

# Loading from an existing file 
flannLoaded = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher.LoadFromFile("my_file_path")

# Here I want to be able to do knnMatch in 'flannLoaded' without training it.
```

If someone have a clue about such a function as saveTrainedModel and/or LoadFromFile, it would be of great help.

Edit: I have found somethin online to do this in C++ : https://github.com/renweizhukov/LearningOpenCV/blob/master/FlannKnnSavableMatching1toN/src/FlannBasedSavableMatcher.cpp
But it uses trainDescCollection that is not available in the python version.

Many thanks for help,

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, edit your answer with a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so other users have enough details to identify an answer for you.

Comment: There is no real example as I am looking for an answer to an unsolved problem. But I can add a code sample that create a FlannBasedMatcher.

Comment: @Loris `cv2.FlannBasedMatcher` class has `write` and `read` methods as well. Can those help in anyway?

Comment: No this method only save the Index and search Params. Then I will have to train my matcher. What I am looking for is something that allow to save a already trained matcher to a file and be able to load it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to do it by using pyflann module.
First I had to modify **pyflann** (pyflann-1.6.14) and **index** (index-0.2-py37) modules for them to accept python 3 usage.

Then you can savec flann indexes doing:

```
from pyflann.index import FLANN, set_distance_type
 
# creating the data
datas = np.random.rand(1000000, 512)
datas = np.float32(datas)
 
# declaring the FLANN
flann = FLANN()
# build the index from datas
flann.build_index(datas, algorithm="linear", checks=10)
# Saving the index created therebefore
flann.save_index(b"my_saved_flann.txt")
 
# Searched data
searched = datas[i]
searched = np.expand_dims(searched, axis=0)
 
# retrieving the 500 nearest neighbours of searched
results, distances = flann.nn_index(searched, 500)
```